# counter that counts on page loads

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to build a simple counter that will count from 0 to 100 on page load.Here is some that i came out with but does not work. I'll appreciate all the help thanks

```
App.AboutController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    count: 0,
    content: 0,
    counterUp: function() {
        var count = this.get('count') + 1;
        this.set('count', count);
        this.set('content', count % 100);
    }
});
```

Comment: how to you run the counterUp function? if its an action from template, you should place it in actions: object

Comment: So the counter should start as soonest the page loads.... counterUp is been place on the template

Comment: Ok, since the solutions go into different directions: Do you want to count up one (x = x + 1) on each "page load", or should the counter start on page load and go on for itself (like a very basic clock)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a great candidate for a component:

**component**

```
App.TimerCounterComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tick: function() {
    this.incrementProperty('count');
    if (Ember.isEqual(this.get('count'), 100)) {
      this.killCounter();
    } else {
      this.scheduleTick();
    }
  },
  scheduleTick: function() {
    this._counter = Ember.run.later(this, 'tick', 600);
  },
  setup: function() {
    this.set('count', 0);
    this.scheduleTick();
  }.on('didInsertElement'),

  killCounter: function() {
    Ember.run.cancel(this._counter);
  }.on('willDestroyElement')
});
```

**component template**

```
Count: {{count}}
```

then in any template you want to use the component:

```
{{timer-counter}}
```

**EDIT: tidied up the jsbin code a bit**

Bonus round: [full js-bin example](http://jsbin.com/zacolo/5/edit)

Comment: For a clock-like solution one could also use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-clock

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make the counting on controller's property because it would always re-initialize and you would have always zero. You can access the application controller however and this way the property will not reset:

```
// better use Controller because ObjectController is getting deprecated
App.AboutController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['application'],
  count: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.count'),
  content: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.content'),
  counterUp: (function() {
    count = this.get('count') + 1 || 1;
    this.set('count', count);
    this.set('content', count % 100);
  }).on('init')
});
```

If you want, you can initialize count and content properties like this:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  count: 0,
  content: 0
})
```

If you have used the proxying behavior of ObjectController use can replace Controller with it.

Answer (score 1):

As things are, your `counterUp` method has been declared and defined, but is never called. You have to call it in an appropriate hook. In http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wuxesosadi/1/edit?html,css,js,output you find an example that counts whenevere you click on the number.

You want to count "on page load" - a full page loade which restarts the application will always reset the counter. If you mean a transition into the route, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wuxesosadi/4/edit?html,css,js,output would be a working example.

That said, for real world problems you would probably have a counter service or the data in a model. The controller should only hold presentation logic. And even though the controller is held in memory and re-used (as a singleton), this feels very wrong. Then again, as an example of how things work, this is perfectly valid.

Comment: Just to clarify for readers who come late to the party: This solution is for a counter that counts on page loads. For a clock-like counter see the answer by Kori John Roys.